# I am having with set state in my Shopify App using Node React

Tags: reactjs, shopify-app, polaris

I am making a Shopify app using Shopify Polaris.
I used the ActionList component.
https://polaris.shopify.com/components/actions/action-list

I want to change the state value on the onAction event.
I did like this.

```
   const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');
   const handleAction = (value) => {
      setSearchValue(value);
   }
   const a = ["A","B"];

   const searchResultsMarkup = (

    <ActionList
       items={[
            {
              content: a[0],
              onAction: handleAction(a[0]),
            },
            {
              content: a[1],
              onAction:  handleAction(a[1]),
            },
    />
    
  );
```

I am a beginner in React.
So maybe a silly question.
but kindly teach me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are passing it down as a prop, so you will have to change it within the  Component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Parent = () => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');
  const handleAction = value => {
    setSearchValue(value);
  }
  return <ActionList changeSearchVal={handleAction} />
}

export const ActionList = ({ changeSearchVal }) => {
  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" onChange={e => changeSearchVal(e.target.value)}/>
    </form>
  )
}
```

If you want to change the searchValue within ActionList.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
Do you know how to update the state value without using useEffect.
So I want to destroy the async.